# How do you remove outliers in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I am currently trying to remove outliers in R in a very easy way. I know there are functions you can create on your own for this but I would like some input on this simple code and why it does not seem to work?

```
outliers <- boxplot(okt$pris)$out

okt_no_out <- okt[-c(outliers),]

boxplot(okt_no_out$pris)
```

The first row I create a vector with the outliers, the second I create a new dataframe omitting the values in that vector. But... When I check the new dataframe only about 400 of the 750 outliers were removed?

The vector outliers contain roughly 750 rows, but when doing this it only remove about half of them....

Should not these simple lines of code remove the outliers in a very convenient way?

Comment: I guess you removed the original outliers. But then that made the whiskers shrink and there were new outliers in the reduced set.  A minimal reproducible example is required to be sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boxplot$out` is returning the values for the outliers and not the positions of the outliers. So `okt[-c(outliers),]` is removing random points in the data series, some of them are outliers and others are not.

What you can do is use the output from the boxplot's stats information to retrieve the end of the upper and lower whiskers and then filter your dataset using those values.  See the example below:

```
#test data
testdata<-iris$Sepal.Width

#return boxplot object
b<-boxplot(testdata)

#find extremes from the boxplot's stats output
lowerwhisker<-b$stats[1]
upperwhisker<-b$stats[5]

#remove the extremes
testdata<-testdata[testdata>lowerwhisker & testdata<upperwhisker]

#replot
b<-boxplot(testdata)
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick! but, to remove the extremes I had to use the specific column instead of the dataframe - testdata <- testdata[testdata$pris<lower & testdata$pris>upper]

Comment: I typed < and > wrong in the comment above, it should be the other way

Comment: @Dave2e  How this technique can be applied to whole DataFrame as I am not getting what to choose as extremes ?

Comment: @suryarahul, I am not understanding your question.  If you pass a data frame to the box plot function, then b$stats will return a matrix of value, the columns are the variables and the rows are the 5 stats (lower, 25%, median, 75% and upper whisker)

Comment: @Dave2e What will be the `lowerwhisker` & `upperwhisker` if I pass full `iris` data to `boxplot` function?

Comment: @suryarahul, I am not sure what your question is nor your expected results. I suggest asking a new question, instead of side tracking this question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `c(outliers)` is the vector of outliers, not the row numbers; so when you add it inside `[ ]` for indexing, it doesn't delete the rows in which the outliers are on. On the other hand, `-c(which(okt$pris %in% outliers))` returns the row numbers of which the outliers are on. Hope this helps!

```
#filter outliers
outliers <- boxplot(okt$pris)$out

#drop the rows containing outliers
okt_no_out <- okt[-c(which(okt$pris %in% outliers)),]

#boxplot without outliers
boxplot(okt_no_out$pris)
```

Comment: Please give more information about you sample code. I don't know which language or which library do you use.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to explain how this works. "Hope this helps!" doesn't actually help at all.

Comment: @BuffK, this is R with no libraries. I think Lucas has copied the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782522/remove-outliers-from-data-frame-in-r).

Comment: Just edited the comment, sorry I wasn't being super clear!