# How can I find the upper and the lower limits of a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss3pE.png)I have built a boxplot in R with certain parameteres but i don´t know the code to help me to know the upper and the lower limits of the box. If anyone could help i would appreciate. I know the quantilies just don´t know the upper and lower limits.

Comment: Please edit your question and add reproducible code on what you have tried so far.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201016/remove-outliers-in-r-very-easy/53209680#53209680

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check examine `stats` of the box-plot. Consider the example below:

```
set.seed(5)
x = rnorm(20)

my.boxplot = boxplot(x)
```

This will plot the following box-plot

[image: sample box plot]

In order to find the values of the upper and lower whiskers and the quartiles we can examine the `stats` of the box plot object:

```
> my.boxplot$stats
           [,1]
[1,] -2.1839668   # Lower whisker
[2,] -0.8213175   # Q1
[3,] -0.3789700   # Q2 (median)
[4,]  0.1041255   # Q3
[5,]  1.3843593   # Upper whisker

# Equvalently:
boxplot(x)$stats
           [,1]
[1,] -2.1839668   # Lower whisker
[2,] -0.8213175   # Q1
[3,] -0.3789700   # Q2 (median)
[4,]  0.1041255   # Q3
[5,]  1.3843593   # Upper whisker
```

To get the values of the outliers you can use the following:

```
> my.boxplot$out
[1] 1.711441   # This example has only one outlier

# or
> boxplot(x)$out
[1] 1.711441   # This example has only one outlier
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `range` parameter inside the `boxplot` function. 
On the help page you can find the details:

> **range**: this determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the box. If range is positive, the whiskers extend to the most extreme
>   data point which is no more than range times the interquartile range
>   from the box. A value of zero causes the whiskers to extend to the
>   data extremes.

The interquantile range is simply the difference between the 75% quantile and the 25% quantile.